# Using glmm_funs.R?

Tags: r, functional-programming

I am fitting a GLMM and I had seen some examples where is used the function: overdisp_fun, deﬁned in glmm_funs.R, but I don't know which package contain them or how can I call it from R, can somebody help me?
Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

If you google for `glmm_funs.R`, you'll find links to the script (eg here: http://glmm.wdfiles.com/local--files/trondheim/glmm_funs.R).

You can save the file on your local machine, then call it in your R session with `source("path to file/glmm_funs.R")`.

You will then be able to use the functions contained in the script, including `overdisp_fun()`.

You can think of it a little bit like loading a package, except the functions are just presented in a script.